# When are matrices $AB$ and $BA$ similar?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ or $B$ is invertible, it is easy to see that $AB$ and $BA$ are similar. I'm curious about when (maybe a strong sufficient or necessary condition) they become similar.

Here's what I have done:

There exists invertible matrices $P, Q$ such that $A=P\begin{pmatrix} I_r &\\ &0\end{pmatrix}Q$ where $r=\text{rank} A$. Let $B=Q^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} B_{11} & B_{12}\\ B_{21}&B_{22}\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$.Then $AB=P\begin{pmatrix} B_{11} & B_{12}\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$ and $BA=Q^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} B_{11} & 0\\ B_{21}&0\end{pmatrix}Q$. Hence we just need to find when $\begin{pmatrix} B_{11} & B_{12}\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} B_{11} & 0\\ B_{21}&0\end{pmatrix}$ are similar.

Now if $B_{11}$ is invertible, let $R=\begin{pmatrix} C  &0\\D&F\end{pmatrix}$ and then $R^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} B_{11} & 0\\ B_{21}&0\end{pmatrix}R=\begin{pmatrix} C^{-1}B_{11}C & 0\\ -F^{-1}DC^{-1}B_{11}C+F^{-1}B_{21}C&0\end{pmatrix}$. Known that $\begin{pmatrix} B_{11} & B_{12}\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix} B_{11}^t & 0\\ B_{12}^t&0\end{pmatrix}$, we just check when the matrices above are equal.

First, there exists $C$ s.t. $C^{-1}B_{11}C=B_{11}^t$ since $B_{11}$ and $B_{11}^t$ are similar.
Second, $-F^{-1}DC^{-1}B_{11}C+F^{-1}B_{21}C=B_{12}^t\Leftrightarrow DB_{11}^t+FB_{12}^t=B_{21}C$. Hence if $\text{rank} \begin{pmatrix} B_{11} &B_{12} \end{pmatrix} = r$ then $D, F$ exist. Disappointingly, however, we need $F$ to be invertible. I cannot overcome this problem but I still have the romantic guess that **$\text{rank}AB=\text{rank}BA=\text{rank}A$ even $\text{rank} AB=\text{rank} BA$ might be a sufficient condition** (please tell me a counter-example so I could give up).

Of course, $F$ might not be invertible really. So if there is a way then that way must consider both $AB$ and $BA$. A weaker result we can get is if $B_{11}$ is invertible then $F=I, D=(B_{21}C-B_{12}^t){B_{11}^t}^{-1}$ satisfies the equation. But I cannot tell what $B_{11}$'s invertibility actually means. I wonder **if there is a direct relation from $A$, $B$ (or $AB$, $BA$) to $B_{11}$**.

I'll appreciate any discussions about this topic.

P.S. I know $AB$ and $BA$ are not similar when $A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. That's just when $F$ is not invertible. Thanks for commenting anyway.

Comment: Example when $AB$ and $BA$ are not similar: when $A=\begin{pmatrix}&1\\&\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&\\&\end{pmatrix}$, we have $AB=0$ but $BA=A\ne0$.

Comment: first impression, given the answer below, also try both matrices nilpotent, for which it suffices to demand strictly upper diagonal. One may take them in Jordan form already, which will be all elements zero except for some $a_{i, i+1}$   and a few $b_{k,k+1} .$   Not entirely sure how it comes uot

Comment: What I eventually get:
If $rank(AB)=rank(BA)$ and $rank(ABA)=rank(AB)$ or $rank(ABA)=0$, then $AB$ and $BA$ are similar. On the other hand, if $0 < rank(ABA) < rank(AB)$ then there exists a counter example.

Answer (score 2):

In general, two matrices $X$ and $Y$ are similar over an algebraically closed field $F$ if an only if $\operatorname{rank}\left((\lambda I-X)^k\right)=\operatorname{rank}\left((\lambda I-Y)^k\right)$ for all $\lambda\in F$ and $k\ge1$. However, in case $X=AB$ and $Y=BA$ for some square matrices $A$ and $B$, one only needs to check the previous condition for $\lambda=0$. In other words, $AB$ and $BA$ are similar if and only if $\operatorname{rank}\left((AB)^k\right)=\operatorname{rank}\left((BA)^k\right)$ for every integer $k\ge1$.

Merely $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(BA)$ is not enough to guarantee that $AB$ is similar to $BA$. Here is a random counterexample where $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(BA)=2$ but $(AB)^2=0\ne(BA)^2$:
\begin{aligned}
AB&=\pmatrix{1&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&1&0&0}
\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&1&1}
=\pmatrix{0&1&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0},\\
BA&=\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&1&1}
\pmatrix{1&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&1&0&0}
=\pmatrix{0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&1&2&0}.\\
\end{aligned}

However, that $\operatorname{rank}(AB)=\operatorname{rank}(BA)=\operatorname{rank}(A)$ is sufficient for the similarity between $AB$ and $BA$. In this case, we may continue from your approach. By [Roth's removal rule](https://doi.org/10.2307/2031890), both $\pmatrix{B_{11}&B_{12}\\ 0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{B_{11}&0\\ B_{21}&0}$ and similar to $\pmatrix{B_{11}&0\\ 0&0}$. In fact, we can exhibit the similarity transforms explicitly:
\begin{aligned}
&\pmatrix{I&B_{11}^{-1}B_{12}\\ 0&I}
\pmatrix{B_{11}&B_{12}\\ 0&0}
\pmatrix{I&-B_{11}^{-1}B_{12}\\ 0&I}\\
&=\pmatrix{B_{11}&0\\ 0&0}\\
&=\pmatrix{I&0\\ -B_{21}B_{11}^{-1}&I}
\pmatrix{B_{11}&0\\ B_{21}&0}
\pmatrix{I&0\\ B_{21}B_{11}^{-1}&I}.
\end{aligned}

Comment: Yeah, but perhaps I did not express my question clearly. There are two things I'm thinking about: 1. is $\text{rank}AB=\text{rank}BA=\text{rank}A$ sufficient? 2. is there a direct way to observe the property of $B_11$ (like the invertibility) from the original $A,B$?